# OpenTBS / PHP / PowerPoint Template - How do I merge text across multiple slides?

Tags: php, opentbs

I am trying to merge a text to multiple slides using OpenTBS but can not get the [a.ProjectName] to be replaced in the title of multiple slides.

I followed the demo in OpenTBS but when I use the code below to retrieve the Project Name I can not get the block substitution to succeed.

This is the code I have used:

```
  $data = array ('ProjectName' => $manageProjectName->getProjectName());

  $TBS->MergeBlock('a', $data);

  $TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_SELECT_SLIDE, 1, true);  //true means use slide master but it is not having any effect
```

How can I get the [a.ProjectName] to be replaced with the contents of the ProjectName across multiple slides and merge contents of ProjectName to multiple slides using OpenTBS?

Comment: `[a.ProjectName]` is displayed on several slides because it is repeated on each slide or because it is defined once in a master slide ?

Comment: I have it repeated because it is on master slide but still can not get it to display the contents on merge.   Is my code incorrect, and if so how do I merge this master slide's content with the ProjectName value so that instead of [a.ProiectName] appearing on the output, ProjectName's value appears?

Comment: Seems to work when I use the OpenTBS example powerpoint template but only on one slide and not on slide master.  When I try to manually edit the tagged name [onshow.yourname] it does not work after I save the template file.  Still trying to get this to work.

Comment: I changed my approach by finally generating the powerpoint xml file first and manually editing its contents before converting the pptx format but no matter what I try I can not get the tag to get its value on output.  I am placing my tag in the slide master.

Comment: I can now render the value of [onshow.ProjectName] on only the first chart.  The other charts show the template tag (i.e. [onshow.ProjectName]).  Do I need to specify the chart / slide to be displaying the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the points to take in account in your case :

- You have to select a slide before to merge something on it (`MergeBlock()`, `MergeField()`, and automatic fields `[onload]`, `[onshow]`).
- But OpenTBS automatically select the normal slide #1 when you call LoadTemplate().
- Master slides are specific slides that you have to select explicitly with command OPENTBS_SELECT_SLIDE.

Another problem in your snippet is that you seem to confuse `MergeBlock()` and `MergeField()`. MergeBlock() is for merging data that are recordsets (several records, having several fields) ; thus the block is repeated as many times as they are records. MergeField() is for merging items, just like in your snippet.

So your code should be:

```
$data = array ('ProjectName' => $manageProjectName->getProjectName());

// Merging [a.ProjectName] in the master slide #1
$TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_SELECT_SLIDE, 1, true); 
$TBS->MergeField('a', $data);

// Merging [a.ProjectName] in the normal slide #1
$TBS->Plugin(OPENTBS_SELECT_SLIDE, 1); 
$TBS->MergeField('a', $data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I used the normal slide merging code and it worked across all slides.